# How to clear the cache?

Tags: wp-query, wp-admin, cache

I have made changes in my CSS, but it doesn't work. I know it's because of caching from admin panel.

How to clear cache of my WordPress admin. Is there any method to clear the cache?

Comment: How are you sure that it's because of cache?

Comment: Are you sure your browser is not caching the CSS file?

Answer (score 9):

Have you looked at [`WP_Object_Cache`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Object_Cache)?

If you suspect there is unwanted caching happening in the code that generates the admin panel then you might be able to use functions from the WP_Object_Cache to clear it.

> WP_Object_Cache is WordPress' class for caching data which may be 
>   computationally expensive to regenerate, such as the result of complex database queries.

Try the function `wp_cache_flush()`  which clears all cached data.

Comment: Please elaborate a bit more, post the relevant code as an example from that link

Answer (score 1):

I wonder why not you [Googled](https://www.google.com/search?q=wordress+disable+cache&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a) and solved it first?

Unlike Drupal, WordPress by default doesn't have any Mass-Caching. The problem you are facing is well cited here:

> - [I Make Changes and Nothing Happens](http://codex.wordpress.org/I_Make_Changes_and_Nothing_Happens)

But for a quick check, open the `wp-config.php` (In the root of your WP installation, where there are three folders: *wp-admin*, *wp-content*, and *wp-includes* present) and check if `'WP_CACHE'` is `'true'`. Just make it `'false'`:

```
define('WP_CACHE', 'false');
```

Or, you can simply remove the line. (The `WP_CACHE` is better cited [in this article](http://funcdoc.wordpress.com/tag/wp_cache/).)

If you are using any plugin for Caching, then the settings panel of the plugin will have a "Clear Cache" button. As per as I know, [WP Super Cache Plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-super-cache/) has such button.

Comment: but i am not using any cache plugin

Comment: Check the updated answer.

Comment: can you tell me location of file?in which folder ?

Comment: `wp-config.php` - In the root of your WP installation, where there are three folders: `wp-admin`, `wp-content`, and `wp-includes` present.

Comment: flase is noy worked

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function wp_cache_flush() {
    global $wp_object_cache;

    return $wp_object_cache->flush();
}

?>
```

Create a new file say "flush.php" with above code in the root of your WordPress installation.

Visit, yoursite.com/flush.php

Answer (score 0):

If you using cPanel for your site maybe you activate (or your hosting provider) Optimize WebSite option. Go to your cPanel and find "**Optimize Website**" page on Sowftware section.

After that set"**Compress Content**" to **disabled**.

Also if you changed your `.htaccess` file (this file located in your public_html folder) maybe you add any deflate or gzip code into. Change this file's content to (**please make backup before editing**)

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to clear from the admin panel using "Flush Cache" ? if not, please try it. the option is on the admin panel under "Managed Wordpress". See photo below. I hope this helps

Comment: I guess this is specific to your host because I haven't seen a 'Managed WordPress' menu before.

Comment: (and I don't see the photo?)

Comment: You are right, that solutions is for Go daddy wordpress